# 2014 Ford Fusion rear seat heating

Tags: ford, fusion

I'm trying to add rear seat heating to my 2014 Ford Fusion. The pads are in, and wiring is next. It needs accessories 12V and 10A. What's the colour of this wire and where would be a good connection point? I am expecting a thick wire, like about 10 gauge.

By the way, instructions are here and I have the version with the single dial: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_cPW1UJkcRmU2lMbWEwTHFReGVHd001TUxISFVQQk1uTWxN

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards 
Janos

Answer (score 3):

There isn't going to be "stock" wiring to support what you need. This means you'll need to run additional wiring (of your own) to compensate. My suggestion is to do the following:

1. Run the necessary wiring in the gauge of wiring of your choice. A 10A circuit can be run off of 16AWG wire, but I'd run it a bit higher ... something like 12AWG. This is a bit of overkill, but will service your needs without issue. 10AWG would be major overkill, but if this is what you've got, you'll have no issue using it.
2. Run the power directly from the battery, then through a fuse (10A), through a relay, to the switch, and then to the seat warmer. This will provide you all the protection you need. The relay should be activated from an ignition on source. This will keep you from running the battery down if someone leaves the seat warmer in the on position when you shut the car down.
3. Run the ground (earth) connection out to somewhere on the car body which will continue to provide a solid connection. This could be just about anything, like a stud with a nut on it. It doesn't really matter, so long as it has continuity back to the (-) on the battery. You can test any place you choose with a multimeter fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Might be simpler as I the relay is already on the wiring harness of the heating pads. But, then why would they advise against doing this?

Comment: So I got power straight from the battery. However I still need an ignition power source where I need to connect the relay. I wanted to use the 12v (lighter) jack in the back, but it turns out that is connected to a constant source of power too. Can anyone recommend a good place to get ignition power?